# Python: Import Excel Data and lookup values in Dictionary

Tags: python, lookup

Total beginner to python: Trying to import excel values from a column. Lookup the imported values in python dictionary (was able to create this) and then write the results into the excel file and see if they match to another column in the file.

Comment: use pandas library.  excel_df = pd.read_excel(filepath).  Use a merge/mapping to apply your dictionary to every value in target column.  Compare this new column to the column of interest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No my question didn't request a step by step instruction but rather a direction as stated I'm a newbie.  the Answer provided by flyingmeatball was of great assistance to send me in an efficient direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a module called `pandas`.

```
pip install pandas
```

To read the file use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.ExcelFile('path/to/excelsheet/').parse('sheet_you_want_to_use') # 'Sheet 1' for Sheet 1
```

you can now access the columns using the column names as keys: `file['column_name']`.

You can now append the looked up values to a list. Then write to a excel file as follows:

```
list = ['....values....']
pd.DataFrame(list).to_excel('where/to/save/file')
```

I would advise you to read the following documentation:

- [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)
- [pandas ExcelFile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html)
- [pandas to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)
- [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)